# How to add "backspace character" to regex output change in vscode?

Tags: regex, search, visual-studio-code

I have file containing around ~1400 lines. In each line there are infomation + in next line is next information which I want move "to previous" line (where is text)

I tried " for" changing into "\r |" - only that was coming to my head in that time.

For example here it's "structure" of my file:

```sh
T="topic 1"
 for xxx@xxx.com
T="topic 2"
 for yyy@yyy.com
```

I wanted move that to clear into that

```sh
T="topic 1" | for xxx@xxx.com
T="topic 2" | for yyy@yyy.com
```

Comment: man you're god :D can I replace that "for" too? (in text lines there are "for" words too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

**Find what**:      `\n( for)\b`
**Replace with**:  `|$1`

**Details**

- `\n` - a line break
- `( for)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1`): a space and `for`
- `\b` - word boundary.

Test result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option if you don't want keep `for` could be to match:

```
\n[ \t]+for[ ]
```

That will match:

- `\n` Match a line break
- `[ \t]+` Match 1+ times a space or char (Or just a single space if that is the case)
- `for[ ]` Match `for` followed by a space (the square brackets are for clarity only

And replace with a space, a pipe followed by a space

`|`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DfNHnn/1)

Comment: Actually, in VSCode, `\n` matches any *linebreak*. Not just a newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah ok, I did not know that, thank you.